# database implementation in php yii framework

Tags: yii

I am using phpmyadmin mysql database for yii framework but i cant create a new app using command prompt, instead i go on

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\framework\yiic\webapp ..\\..\\yiitestapp
```

and then cmd opens and it asks for yes/no. my cmd does not works

I have already set my environment variables to `c:\xampp\php`

Please reply how would I create a new app with database table using phpmyadmin.

Comment: What happens when u say Yes in cmd prompt

Comment: my testapp is created inside htdocs and it runs well but my cmd closes automatically after i write yes

Comment: Ok u can use an alternative tool gii to create tables and models ,have u read yii documentation ??

Comment: yes i have already used gii tool. though i have done fine by reading documentation I am not getting it. i am getting an error: CException Property "User.content" is not defined.

Comment: i have gone through the yiiframework documentation section inside that there is screencasts the last or say 4th screencast is not working for me

Comment: It means u don't have a field named Content in the user table

Comment: ok now i get i was doing without understanding thanx for the reply its true my user table has different field. But how can I call all fields of my table because my table contains three feilds username, password and email

Comment: thanx Ninad, its working very well. But i want to know how can I display all fields of my table

Comment: Create the model and crud for your table and display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your comments i came to know that you are using windows, wamp server package 
in your local m/c 
based on this assumption

you can use

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

to create your database
create edit and delete tables

then use

```
http://localhost//*yor web application name*/?r=gii
```

to access gii tools

pls let me know if any problem persist

Comment: no actually its xampp with http://localhost/phpmyadmin. My application runs well but i know how to retrieve and show all data from my database with all entered id

Comment: @Phpdeveloper developer then change your question to make me know about your actual need

Comment: thanks and my application is running well also I got my answer. thankx for helping.

Comment: you can implement database using  gii tools, very easily, to your web app

Comment: thanks@ Samuel J Mathew, yeah i used gii tools and my application is working fine